# Eliminate whitespaces in directory command-line arguments

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, directory, mingw

A number of folders I possess have name with spaces.
This apparently causes a problem when attempting to compile a source file located in such folder. How do I ignore whitespaces for gcc compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes around your command

```
gcc "C:\my file.c" -o "C:\my folder\my file.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn´t know that. This is what the IDE causes to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape spaces using `\`

eg:

```
$ gcc -o bin /media/code\ folder/code.c
```

Comment: Oh useful. I was thinking of something like that too.